# Default ordering of a Map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map as follows:

```
std::map<A, long> myMap
```

The ordering of this map is important so I am trying to figure out how the map will be ordered. I have found that on the documentation of this class it says *Internally, the elements in the map are sorted from lower to higher key value following a specific strict weak ordering criterion set on construction* but I don't understand what this means. Will it call the '<' operator on the two objects to figure out the ordering?

I am also aware that I could just pass the map a struct as follows on initialisation and it will do as I want. I am just curious as to what it does by default.

```
struct classcomp {
  bool operator() (const A& lhs, const A& rhs) const
   {return lhs<rhs;}
};
```

Comment: FYI, your functor is, for all intents, *identical* to std::less<>, which is what is used by default.

Comment: _By default_, it will do what your `classcomp` structure is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it call the '<' operator on the two objects to figure out the ordering?

Yes, it will:

```
struct A {
    bool operator<(const A& other) const
    {
        return ...; // return true if *this is less than other; false otherwise
    }
};
```

Make sure that the "less than" relation defined by your `operator<` is transitive, i.e. if `A < B` and `B < C`, then `A` must be less than `C` as well.

Comment: I don't know what the property is called, but it also needs to satisfy: `if !(A<B) and !(B<C) then !(A<C)`, which you can get caught up on if, for example, you try to implement an epsilon comparison on floating point numbers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That's the transitivity of `X >= Y`, a dangerous thing to break. Yet suggestions to do it come up regularly - in fact, I remember reading Dijkstra's recollections about making the equality checker in Algol-60 use an epsilon, and then quickly dropping the idea after discovering that doing so would break transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

By default it call `less<A>` which is `operator <` (at least if it isn't specialized)

You may do `std::map<A, long, classcomp> myMap` if you need another way to sort

Answer (score 0):

By default `std::map` will use `std::less` to compare two keys. By default `std::less` looks very much like your `classcomp` and uses `<` to do the comparison. You can override the default behavior by either passing a different comparison function or object, or by creating `operator<` for your type.